# Create a function in Databricks notebook for spark.sql

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a function in scala that would write a log message to delta table.
example

```
def logMessage(message: String): Unit = {
spark.sql("INSERT INTO tablename values ('${message}')")
}
```

The problem is that spark.sql will return DataFrame, but in my notebook I want to execute this method in various catch blocks to log error. Obviously the return type does not match. How to write this function that would return unit and I could use it in multiple catch blocks ?

Comment: I didn't know is that simple, thanks